# Convert array<string> to string

Tags: sql, arrays, string, hive, hiveql

I have a hive array of string and I want to convert it to string. Hive version is 1.2.1000.2.6.1.0-129.

```
create table a (arr array<string>);

create table b (str array<string>);

insert into table b
select * from a;
```

I tried:

```
concat_ws(',',collect_set(cast(arr as string))

collect_set(cast(arr as string))

cast(arr as string)
```

Comment: Thanks but not working for me

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concat_ws()` function (concatenate with separator) concatenates array elements into string separated with specified separator (comma in this example):

```
concat_ws(',',arr) as result
```